# Resolvent inequality follows it's boundness

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, banach-algebras

Following is from my lecture notes. I have resolvent map $R(\cdot,x): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow A$, where $x\in A$ Banach algebra. Domain is whole complex numbers because for the sake of contradiction it was assumed spectrum is empty.

Then one argues from $ \Vert R(\lambda,x) \Vert \leq \frac{1}{|\lambda | - \Vert x \Vert}$ for any lambda $|\lambda | > \Vert x \Vert$ that  $R(\cdot,x)$ is bounded function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Question: Why is $R(\cdot,x)$ bounded?

Comment: Write $R(\lambda,x)$ with the help of [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

Comment: That would be then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty = \lambda^{-k}x^{k-1}$. Shall I substitute this in the inequality and follow boundness? Or is it not quite the direction of your hint? @user10354138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $|\lambda|\leq\|x\|$, as you say in the comments,
$$
R(\lambda,x)=(\lambda-x)^{-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda^{-k}\,x^{k-1}. 
$$
Then
$$
\|R(\lambda, x)\|\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\lambda|^{-k}\,\|x\|^{k-1}=\frac1{|\lambda|-\|x\|}.
$$
This requires using that $\Big\|\sum_k y^k\Big\|\leq\sum_k\|y\|^k$. This follows from the fact that the norm is continuous, the triangle inequality, and the submultiplicativity of the norm.

Here is another argument without the Neumann series. Given $a\in A$ such that $\|a\|<1$, then $1+a$ is invertible and $\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$
\begin{align*}
1&=\|(1+a)(1+a)^{-1}\|=\|(1+a)^{-1}+a(1+a)^{-1}\|\abajo
&\geq\|(1+a)^{-1}\|-\|a(1+a)^{-1}\|\abajo
&\geq\|(1+a)^{-1}\|-\|a\|\,\|(1+a)^{-1}\|.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\tag1
\|(1+a)^{-1}\|\leq\frac1{1-\|a\|}. 
$$
Now, when $\|x\|<|\lambda|$ we apply $(1)$ to $a=x/|\lambda|$ to get
$$
\|(\lambda-x)^{-1}\|\leq\frac1{|\lambda|-\|x\|}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! But I still don't understand how it follows from inequality that $R(\cdot,x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$. The term $\frac{1}{|\lambda|-\Vert x \Vert}$ is unbounded...

Comment: Oh, that was not clear from your question. Separately, one proves that the function is entire. In particular it is continuous so is it bounded on any closed disk. The inequality above only addresses the case $|\lambda|>\|x\|$, but in particular it tells you that $R(\cdot,x)$ is bounded outside of the disk of radius $2|\lambda|$, say.

Comment: Now is clear, thank you very much!